# different modes to typest systems of equations

Tags: equations, arrays

Would it be bad style to use in displaymode an array with three colums that are right-center-left ("`rcl`") oriented instead of `eqnarray`, to  typeset systems of differential of equations ?
The spacing between the columns then seems to look like and `eqnarray` - but the spaces between the rows are then less than in `eqnarray` and all the fractures are textsize, not normal size.

The reason have used this was because by using an array, I can reference the whole system with a single number, not just  lines at a time.  The reference number would thus be displayed on vertically in the middle and not near a specific line, like when using `eqnarray`. Is there a way to also reference a whole system when using  `eqnarray` ?

Comment: Package `amsmath` provides many environments for aligning equations.

Comment: having the spacing look like `eqnarray` should be a non-aim, it is really one of the poorer parts of the base latex system. Always use the amsmath alignments instead, they provide the features you ask for here.

Comment: To have a single equation number apply to an aligned system of equations, just load the `amsmath` package and use a `split` environment inside an `equation` environment.